# When I post something with Pusher, and reload the page, all entries disappear. How to fix? Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, pusher

Here's where I'm triggering the Pusher event.

```
@app.route('/post-question', methods=['POST'])
def add_question():
    data_received = json.loads(request.data)
    data = {
        'id':'post-{}'.format(uuid.uuid4().hex),
        'title':data_received['title'],
        'question':data_received['content'],
        'status': 'active',
        'event_name': 'created'
    }
    pusher.trigger("CHANNEL", 'question-created', data)
    return jsonify(data)
```

Here's the Pusher channel binding:

```
    <script>
        
        function appendToList(data) {
            const html = `
                <div id="${data.id}">
                        <header>
                            <h1>${data.title}</h1>
                        </header>
                        <div>
                            <p>${data.question}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div> `
                    let list = document.querySelector('#post-list')
                    list.innerHTML += html
        }

        $(document).ready(() => {
            $(document).on('click', "#submit", function(event) {
                $.post({
                    url: '/post-question',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: JSON.stringify({'title': $("#question-title").val(), 'content': $("#question-content").val()}),
                    success : function(response) {
                        console.log(response);  
                    },
                    error : function(xhr) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                    }
                }).done(function(response) {
                    $("#question-form").reset()
                })
            })
        })

        Pusher.logToConsole = true;
        
        const pusher = new Pusher('*', {
          cluster: '*',
          encrypted: true 
        });

        const channel = pusher.subscribe('CHANNEL')

        channel.bind('question-created', data => {
            appendToList(data);
        })
    </script>
```

It correctly triggers the event, and appears correctly in another window in real time, but for some reason, when I reload the page, all the posts disappear; and the post disappears on the current window as well.

I think it might be a problem with the way I am rendering the posts, but I don't know. Anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not so familiar with pusher, but in your code I don't see anywhere where you fetch the already existing posts? I see code for creating a new post, but not for fetching the old ones

Comment: Yeah, thanks Reed, I don't know why I didn't think about doing this, but I think I might have found a way to fix it. I'll post it as the answer if it works. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First comment is correct. Pusher takes care of real-time communication and new events. For showing old/existing posts every time page (re)loads, you need to query and render them in your app. You can choose to do that server-side or client-side.

Comment: Correct: Pusher has a suggested implementation for this too https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019262174-How-do-I-implement-message-event-history-for-Channels-